# How to use SQL Data Adapter Update command to update a row in data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

So far I managed to use Insert command to create a new record inside a table called ***"Students"***. This is the code i used:

```
        int ID = int.Parse( TextBox1.Text);
        string name = TextBox2.Text;
        string gender = TextBox3.Text;
        int marks = int.Parse(TextBox4.Text);



        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            //create data adapter 
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from students",con);

            //create sqlcommand to store execute stored procedure
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("spInsertStudent",con);
            adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //create parameter for Return value (@ROWCOUNT)
            SqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ROWCOUNT",SqlDbType.Int);
            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ID");
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50,"Name");
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Gender",SqlDbType.NVarChar,10,"Gender");
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalMarks",SqlDbType.Int,0,"TotalMarks");

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //DataTable students = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(ds,"Students");

            DataTable students = ds.Tables["Students"];

            DataRow studentRow = students.NewRow();
            studentRow["ID"] = ID;
            studentRow["Name"] = name;
            studentRow["Gender"] = gender;
            studentRow["TotalMarks"] = marks;
            students.Rows.Add(studentRow);


            adapter.Update(ds,"Students");
```

Now I want to edit a data row. The data will be change if the ID is matched with the ID parameter. This is the stored procedure I'm using:

```
create procedure updateStudent 
@ID int,
@Name varchar(50),
@Gender varchar(10),
@TotalMarks int

AS
BEGIN
    update Students set Name = @Name, Gender = @Gender, TotalMarks = @TotalMarks
    where ID = @ID
END
```

and this is the C# code i use in the code behind:

```
        int ID = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        string name = TextBox2.Text;
        string gender = TextBox3.Text;
        int marks = int.Parse(TextBox4.Text);

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Students",con);
            DataTable dtStudents = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dtStudents);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("updateStudent",con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ID").Value = ID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name").Value = name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, "Gender").Value = gender;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalMarks", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "TotalMarks").Value = marks;
            adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;

            adapter.Update(dtStudents);
        }
```

But after I clicked the Update button on my web form, there is no error message and the data didn't get updated in my database. What have I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write classes for executing stored procedures. It will be more easier to read and handle. RunQuery method in such a class like DB

```
 private SqlConnection Connection;
 public bool Open()
 {
    try
    {
       ConnectionString = "your connection string";
       Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
       Connection.Open();
       return true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
        return false;
     }
 }
 public bool RunQuery(string ProcedureName, SqlParameter[] Parameters)
 {
     bool res = false;
     try
     {
         SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
         Command.CommandText = ProcedureName;
         Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         Command.Connection = Connection;
         Command.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);
         Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         res = true;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         throw ex;
      }
      return res;
  }
```

And you can call it

```
SqlParameter[] param= new SqlParameter[4];
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID", ID);
param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Name", name);
param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Gender", gender);
param[3] = new SqlParameter("@TotalMarks", marks);
RunQuery("updateStudent", param);
```

Comment: HI, I were just trying to test on the code before I actually implement it in my actual project. Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it out.